# What if the vote is equal when ensembling using votingclassifier()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

What happens when, say, 4 models predict two unique outcomes: 1, 1, 0, and 0 . What would `votingclassifier()` do when there is no clear majority.

Comment: What don't you understand from the on-line documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From the sci-kit learn documentation for `VotingClassifier.predict()`

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/ensemble/voting.py#L281

We can see that this function calls `numpy.argmax`

From it's documentation, under "Notes", it says "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

So it would predict the one that occurred first in the list of classifications, in your example `1`.

If the VotingClassifier is using 'soft' voting, and two outcomes have equally likely probability sums, it will predict the one that is first in the list of outcomes